# Rendering List within list(using Map within Map)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I want to render some **List within a list** in JSX. An array of records

```
 const [records, setRecords] = useState([
    {
      name: "Jack",
      record: {
        record_1: { credit: 10, debit: 0, total: 10 },
        record_2: { credit: 10, debit: 0, total: 20 }
      }
    }
  ]);
```

How can i render `name`,list of **record** containing `record_1` & `record_2`

what i want is

[image: This Output of list]

Comment: If my information is in Complete then plz tell me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Object.values`

```js
records.map(value =>
  Object.values(value.record).map(record => <div>
    name: {value.name} {' '}
    credit: {record.credit} {' '}
    debt: {record.debit} {' '}
    total: {record.total}
  <div>)
);
```

snippet:

```js
const Comp = () => {
  const [records, setRecords] = React.useState([
    {
      name: "Jack",
      record: {
        record_1: { credit: 10, debit: 0, total: 10 },
        record_2: { credit: 10, debit: 0, total: 20 }
      }
    }
  ]);

  return records.map(value =>
    Object.values(value.record).map(record => <div>
      name: {value.name} {' '}
      credit: {record.credit} {' '}
      debt: {record.debit} {' '}
      total: {record.total}
    </div>)
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Comp />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: first map could be simplified to `records.map(value...`

Comment: @charlietfl I thought that it's an object too. Thanks.

Comment: Where should i use this snippet. Is this code is running in index.js? if it is, then i know how to work in App.js

Comment: @USAMA It's a React component.